# CONCAT Column SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

I need your help the resolve the following problem

```
     column1    Column2 
          1       a
          1       b
          2       c
          3       d
          4       e
```

I want to contact the elements of col2 for the same value of col1 and return the result as a variable in a single column.

Result : |1|a,b|

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's you dbms?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: i use SQL for Oracle

Answer (score 0):

use concat function

```
 select concat(case when t.column1 is not null then t.column1 else end,
 case when t.column2 is not null then t.column2 else end) as col1 from   your_table as t
inner join
(
select column1 from your_table
group by column1
having count(*)>1
) as T1
t.column1=T1.column1
```

Comment: Is it the same for SQL Oracle, because it's the one that i use ?

Answer (score 0):

Fill tbename and column1,column2 according your need

```
      SELECT  distinct     CAT.column1 AS [column1],
               STUFF((    SELECT ',' + SUB.column2 AS [text()]

                     FROM tbename SUB
                     WHERE
                     SUB.column1 = CAT.column1
                     FOR XML PATH('')
                       ), 1, 1, '' )

        AS [column2]
  FROM  tbename  CAT
```

for oracle  below code 11g+

```
select column1, listagg(column2,',') within group( order by column1 ) 
  from tbename group by gr
```

Comment: Is it the same for SQL Oracle, because it's the one that i use ?

Comment: this code is for SQL server add oracle code it will work foe 11g +